# How do I remove old kernel files from /boot and fix a potential error listed in <sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'>?

Tags: boot, kernel

Any help with the following would be very much appreciated:

A few days ago I installed the latest stable Linux kernel (3.16.3) and then I used the one liner from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435818) to remove my old kernels.
  The command removed a bunch of packages, including my AMD fglrx drivers (I am now running the latest OpenSource Gallium), however it didn't remove the old kernels from /boot (which are not installed anymore). Please see below for details.

```
$ uname -a
Linux linux 3.16.3-031603-generic #201409171435 SMP Wed Sep 17 18:36:23 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ sudo ls -l /boot
total 153701
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1158016 May  3 01:30 abi-3.13.0-24-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1163858 Aug 15 03:56 abi-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1163858 Sep  3 23:24 abi-3.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1204707 Sep 17 20:04 abi-3.16.3-031603-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165510 May  3 01:30 config-3.13.0-24-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165652 Aug 15 03:56 config-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165671 Sep  3 23:24 config-3.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   170795 Sep 17 20:04 config-3.16.3-031603-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Sep 30 13:20 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28803145 Sep 26 18:48 initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26876001 Sep 23 17:05 initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28958561 Sep 26 18:46 initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28616184 Sep 30 13:31 initrd.img-3.16.3-031603-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Aug 28 16:23 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3372643 May  3 01:30 System.map-3.13.0-24-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3386444 Aug 15 03:56 System.map-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3386479 Sep  3 23:24 System.map-3.13.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3629877 Sep 17 20:04 System.map-3.16.3-031603-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5776416 May  3 01:30 vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5806368 Aug 15 03:56 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5806848 Sep  3 23:24 vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6417328 Sep 17 20:04 vmlinuz-3.16.3-031603-generic
```

Now my questions are:

1. How do I correctly delete all the files in my /boot except for the 4 files related to 3.16.3? Can I just manually remove them and then upgrade grub using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?
2. Please see the output of the command below. Since I don't know the meaning of it, could someone please let me know if this displays an error or if this is what I should be seeing?

Thanks a lot! :)

```
$ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-===================================================
un  linux-image             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.0         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.16.3-0316 3.16.3-031603.20 amd64            Linux kernel image for version 3.16.3 on 64 bit x86
```

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidFoerster but my post is not a duplicate. I already performed the steps listed in that tutorial and I was left with all the kernel files still on /boot 
My post also has 2 parts: one that has to do with removing the files manually and the other with the potential error I'm seeing after running $ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' Thanks.

Comment: My bad. The output of `dpkg --list …` seems error free to me. `Err?=` is part of the column labels.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get autoremove`?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of old kernel packages I first check that I am not running the kernel I am about to delete :)

```
uname -a
```

Then I grep for the packages, for example:

```
dpkg -l | fgrep linux-image-
dpkg -l | fgrep 3.13.0-24
```

Then I purge specific kernel packages from that list (the following is just an example, you can copy/paste the actual kernel package names):

```
apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-24-amd64 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-24-amd64
```

If the files in /boot are not being removed correctly for some reason, you could manually remove them, of course, being careful NOT to remove files associated with installed linux-image- versions and NOT to remove files associated with the kernel you are running right now.

After removing files from /boot you can run update-grub to remove the associated menu entries.

The status of 'un' doesn't look quite right to me. You could try:

```
apt-get -f install
```

or

```
apt-get install linux-image
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Gregor. I ended up running gksudo nautilus and removing all old kernels manually. Then I ran update-grub, I reinstalled my fglrx and everything's all right now. 
However, I still don't know if the output I get from 
$ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
is an error or not... Any confirmation would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The status of 'un ' does not not look quite right to me.  You could try